# Get headers of a post request PHP

Tags: python, php, post, request, roblox

I am trying to make a post request to the Roblox API to get an x-csrf token. I've already figured it out in python

```
import requests, json
import requests
authurl = "https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout"
cookie = os.environ['cook']
def getXsrf():
    xsrfRequest = requests.post(authurl, cookies={
        '.ROBLOSECURITY': cookie
    })
    print(xsrfRequest.headers["x-csrf-token"])
    return xsrfRequest.headers["x-csrf-token"]


xsrf = getXsrf()
```

This returns my x-csrf token but if I just print the request like this:

```
def getXsrf():
    xsrfRequest = requests.post(authurl, cookies={
        '.ROBLOSECURITY': cookie
    })
    print(xsrfRequest.json())
    return xsrfRequest.json()


xsrf = getXsrf()
```

It will respond:

```
{'errors': [{'code': 0, 'message': 'Token Validation Failed'}]}
```

I'm attempting to implement the same idea in PHP but I'm not sure how I'd get the header. This is what I've tried so far

```
<?php
$content = $_POST["input"];
$arr = array('.ROBLOSECURITY' => $content);
$cookies = json_encode($arr)."\n";
function curlPost($url, $data = NULL, $headers = []) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');

    
    if (!empty($data)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    if (!empty($headers)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        trigger_error('Curl Error:' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
$response=curlPost("https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout", $cookies);
echo($response)
?>
```

The response is so:

```
{"errors":[{"code":0,"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}]}
```

I'm not sure which function to use to get the header

Comment: Try to pass `{"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"}` to `headers` argument.